# Concatenating PostgreSQL records by column, with max size

Tags: postgresql

How do I concatenate below's records such that they would be concatenated a maximum of 3 records?

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Numbers | One |
| Numbers | Two |
| Numbers | Three |
| Alphabets | A |
| Alphabets | B |
| Alphabets | C |
| Alphabets | D |

Will return:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Numbers | One, Two, Three |
| Alphabets | A, B, C |
| Alphabets | D |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Group by `row_number() / 3`

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH tableA as (
    SELECT tbl.columnA, tbl.columnB, CAST(row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY columnA ORDER BY columnB) as INT) AS row_number
    FROM tbl
    ORDER BY columnA
)
SELECT tableA.columnA, string_agg(DISTINCT columnB, ',  ') as columnB 
FROM tableA
GROUP BY tableA.columnA, row_number/5
```